# How can I access a user's answer for my quiz on a different PHP page?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I currently have a simple quiz on my page quiz_v1.php with 3 possible answers and a submit button. The answer is posted to a separate page, quiz_dest.php, where it currently displays the value for the answer ID (A, B or C).

**quiz_v1.php**

```
    <form action="quiz_dest.php" method="post" id="quiz">
  <ol>
    <li> 
      <!-- display question as heading -->
      <?php
      while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo "<h3>" . $row[ "question" ] . "</h3>";
      }
      ?>
      <!-- display answers as radio -->
      <div>
        <input type= "radio" name="question1_answers" id="question1_answers_A" value="A"/>
        <label for="question1_answers_A">
          <?php while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {echo $row["choice_text"];}?>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type= "radio" name="question1_answers" id="question1_answers_B" value="B"/>
        <label for="question1_answers_A">
          <?php while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {echo $row["choice_text"];}?>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type= "radio" name="question1_answers" id="question1_answers_C" value="C"/>
        <label for="question1_answers_A">
          <?php while($row = $result4->fetch_assoc()) {echo $row["choice_text"];}?>
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit answer"/>
</form>
```

I use the SQL statements below to retrieve the information from my DB.

```
//queries
$sql = "SELECT question FROM Question WHERE question_id = '1'";
$result = $conn->query( $sql );

$sql2 = "SELECT choice_text FROM Question_choices WHERE choice_id = '1' AND question_id = '1'";
$result2 = $conn->query( $sql2 );

$sql3 = "SELECT choice_text FROM Question_choices WHERE choice_id = '2' AND question_id = '1'";
$result3 = $conn->query( $sql3 );

$sql4 = "SELECT choice_text FROM Question_choices WHERE choice_id = '3' AND question_id = '1'";
$result4 = $conn->query( $sql4 );
```

**In quiz_dest.php**

```
$answer1 = $_POST[ "question1_answers" ];
echo "$answer1";
```

I would like to be able to assign to a variable the user's choice_id, carry this over to quiz_dest and use a SQL query to compare the choice_ID with is_right_choice to see if it is the correct answer and then display a message to the user.

I can't quite wrap my head around how I could use $_POST and $_GET to achieve this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have also included a screenshot below of the table in my database.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiP7X.png)

Comment: Where are you defining the user in your query?

Comment: Aren't you already getting the user's choice in your example of quiz_dest.php?  Also, you don't need multiple queries for the question choices.  Grab them all at once and loop through the result.  Also, make sure to sanitize any POST data. Use prepared statements.

Comment: I'm not defining the user as it these answers are going to be confidential. By user I just meant someone using the site @Mech

Comment: @Phaelaxz I am getting their choice, but only as an ID that I set for the radio input, I would like to get it as the choice_ID in the table. Thanks for the advice on the queries.

Answer (score -1):

Use the $_GET[] method. If you are using GET than the answer should appear in the URL *if* the answer goes to another PHP page. You can also try adding the answers to a database and implement some MySQL.